# How to obtain a var inside a function in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

In my game, the player can choose 2, 3 or 4 dices to be rolled then the chosen no. of dices will be rolled and the biggest number wins. However, when user chooses 3 or 4 dices to be rolled, I can't obtain the `var randomNumber1` - `var randomNumber4` inside my event listener that is fired when the submit button is pressed. I need those `var` to continue coding. Can someone please help thanks.

In my 4th last line of javascript code, `if (noOfChoices === "3")`,  `console.log(userChoices);` is not printing even though the case above for `if (noOfChoices === "2")` works. The error message shown on chrome dev tools is:

```
index.js:91 Uncaught ReferenceError: randomNumber1 is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.js:91)
```

Can someone please help thanks.

This is my javascript code:

```
function diceRoll() {
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var Image1 = "dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src", Image1);

  var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var Image2 = "dice" + randomNumber2 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[2].setAttribute("src", Image2);

  var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var Image3 = "dice" + randomNumber3 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[3].setAttribute("src", Image3);

  var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var Image4 = "dice" + randomNumber4 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[4].setAttribute("src", Image4);
}

// Storing user noOfChoices
let links = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')
links.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let numberOfChoices = event.target.innerText
    document.getElementById('dropdownMenu').innerHTML = `${numberOfChoices}<span class="caret"></span>`)})

// Responding to Submit
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

// Storing Data into variables
  var choice1 = $("#choice1").val();
  var choice2 = $("#choice2").val();
  var choice3 = $("#choice3").val();
  var choice4 = $("#choice4").val();
  var noOfChoices = $("#dropdownMenu").text();
  var userChoices = [];

// Displaying no. of dices that user chose
    if (noOfChoices === "2") {
      $("#caption1, #caption2").removeClass("invisible");
      $("#caption3, #caption4").addClass("invisible");
    }

    if (noOfChoices === "3") {
      $("#caption1, #caption2, #caption3").removeClass("invisible");
      $("#caption4").addClass("invisible");
    }

    if (noOfChoices === "4") {
      $(".caption").removeClass("invisible");
    }

$("#submit").html("Again");

// Rolling Dice
diceRoll();

// Determining Winner
if (noOfChoices === "2") {if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2) {$("#title").html(choice1 + " wins! ");}
else if (randomNumber2 > randomNumber1) {$("#title").html(choice2 + " wins! ");}
else if (randomNumber2 = randomNumber1){$("#title").html("Oops, try again!");}
}

if (noOfChoices === "3") {userChoices.push(randomNumber1, randomNumber2,randomNumber3);
console.log(userChoices);
}
})}
```

And here is my html:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-of-images">
      <img src="chick2.png">

      <figure>
        <img id="img1" class="dice" src="dice6.png">
        <figcaption class="caption" id="caption1">Choice 1</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure>
        <img id="img2" class="dice" src="dice6.png">
        <figcaption class="caption" id="caption2">Choice 2</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure class="threeChoices">
        <img id="img3" class="dice" src="dice6.png">
        <figcaption class="caption" id="caption3">Choice 3</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure class="fourChoices">
        <img id="img4" class="dice" src="dice6.png">
        <figcaption class="caption" id="caption4">Choice 4</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <img src="chick1.png">
    </div>

  <div class="container-of-forms">

    <!-- Dropdown Button -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        0
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul id="list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Input Text Fields -->
      <div class="container-inner">  <br>
        <input class="text-input-box" id="choice1" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 1"> <br>
        <input class="text-input-box" id="choice2" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 2"> <br>
        <input class="text-input-box invisible threeChoices" id="choice3" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 3"> <br>
        <input class="text-input-box invisible fourChoices" id="choice4" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 4">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <h5>The bigger number wins!</h5>
  <!-- Submit Button -->
  <a href="" id="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" role="button">Go</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is not possible to get a local variable in another function. You can return the values.

Comment: That just won't work. all `randomNumber` vars are scoped in `diceRoll` so you can't access them outside of `diceRoll`... but there's a way you can work it arround. I'll show you below.

Comment: Btw. you forgot some closing braces at `links.forEach((el) => { ... })});`

Comment: @Sascha I think that the final closing } is at the bottom...or is there another I missed? Sorry I really can't find it.. ok right nvm I added one more } at the bottom thanks

Comment: No this is from the function(r) in `document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {` Using an IDE than you will see that there is missing a `}` and a `) ` from the above mentioned line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not know it, but you are asking about a really, really important Javascript concept called "scope".

Variables have "scopes". Think of a scope as a group of contexts that have access to a variable.

A variable is visible to its "current scope" and all scopes below it. There is always the "global" scope, a.k.a. the outermost runtime environment. If you look at the first line of executable code following your `diceRoll` function definition, you'll see an example of a globally scoped variable: `links`. The variable `links` will be accessible from *anywhere in your program* as long as you are not using some kind of module bundler to modify scopes under the covers (it looks like you're doing some pretty basic programming here, so lets forget about that for now).

Apart from the global scope, we have other scopes as well. One in particular is really important for you to understand: The function scope.

Functions create their own scope. That means anything outside of the function cannot access what is inside of it. It is its own little self-defined scope. Any variables you define in there are not accessible outside of that function. If you think about why, it starts to make sense: Functions are temporary code. They run, and then they're done. Every time you call a function, a new scope is created, the function logic is handled, and then all the variable references are destroyed as long as they aren't passed back to the calling context. This is by design.

What you've done here, then, is create variables, such as `randomNumber1` that *simply do not exist* outside of the scope of the function `diceRoll`.

Now, more advanced programming  techniques would argue that you should *never create global variables*, something that you will eventually learn to adhere to, I guarantee it. But for now, so you can start to get your head around scope, the simplest solution to your problem is to *define your variables* that are *outside* of the `diceRoll` function, and *assign your values to them* from *inside*. Basically, this will fix your problem:

```
// Here, you **define** your variables. This "creates" them, but does not assign them values.
var randomNumber1;
var randomNumber2;
var randomNumber3;
var randomNumber4;
var image1;
var image2;
var image3;
var image4;

// When code execution reaches this point, you could do something like this:
console.log(randomNumber1);
// ^ the above line would log `undefined` to the console, because the variable exists but has no value assigned to it. Great! We're all set, now all your global scope stuff further down can access these variables!

function diceRoll() {
  // Now in here, you simply remove the *var* keyword, since you don't want to *create new variables*, you want to *assign values to the existing ones*. If you use the *var* keyword here, it will create a *new* variable with the same name, but only within the function scope. You will still have the same problem.
  randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  image1 = "dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src", Image1);

  randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  image2 = "dice" + randomNumber2 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[2].setAttribute("src", Image2);

  randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  image3 = "dice" + randomNumber3 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[3].setAttribute("src", Image3);

  randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  image4 = "dice" + randomNumber3 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[4].setAttribute("src", Image4);
}
```

Notices that as a small semantic choice, I declared your Image[x] variable names in camel case (lower case first letter) which is industry standard convention.

Last but not least, lets circle back and re-read the important thing here that helps you figure out the problem: the error itself:

```
index.js:91 Uncaught ReferenceError: randomNumber1 is not defined
  at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.js:91)
```

Lets translate this into english:

`Uncaught ReferenceError`

"Uncaught" means an error was thrown (meaning you had an execution error because you tried to do something that isn't possible for some reason). What was uncaught? An error (it's always an error), specifically of type `ReferenceError`.
As our helpful friend MDN tells us:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError
`The ReferenceError object represents an error when a non-existent variable is referenced.`

Basically, you tried to access a variable that hasn't been defined in the current scope (in your case, the global scope).

Lastly: `randomNumber1 is not defined` <-- that needs no translating. Simply put, there was an error when trying to reference a variable (randomNumber1) because it isn't' defined. The latter part of the error tells you *where*:

`at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.js:91)` <-- index.js on line 91. You can use this to understand what *scope* you are in, so you can properly reference variables within that scope and fix your issue.

The `at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>` is referring to the current step in the call stack and its context - but that is more complex and you can ignore that for now.

So, in summary:

We have moved the *declaration of the variables* you want to access *outside* your function *scope*, and kept the *assignment of values to those variables* so that it still happens *inside* your function. This is extremely important to understand, and I suggest strongly that you do some reading about Javascript and function scope and closures. You will *absolutely need to understand this concept* if you want to become even an entry level JS developer.

Happy to answer any questions you might have. Good luck!

**Edit:**
@Mosia Thabo's answer is also a good example, and I would argue, the "more correct solution". I did not provide that solution on purpose, and that was to keep this to what your question was really about, even if you didn't know it. Note that I mentioned that "globally scoped variables are something you want to always avoid" and you will no doubt come across the phrase "global variables are evil". They are.

My example was to simplify the concept of scope which I feel is the important lesson to learn here. Mosia's answer it *how I would approach it* - the function effectively turns into basically what you would call a generator that *gives you a result set* as a return value. But return values can add confusion so I left that part out.

Scope. Learn. About. Scope.

Comment: Thank you!! That was very informative, will try your method now

Comment: @argonx you're welcome - I just updated the answer to include descriptions of the error message which can also be helpful to understand how to read, in case that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can not reference those values, you can return the values and use them. Simple way is to use an array. Cleaned up code would look like this

```
function rollResult () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
}

function diceRoll() {

  var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

  const dice = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    var number = rollResult();
    dice[i] = number;
    images[i+1].src = "dice" + number + ".png";
  }

  return dice;

}

var diceResult = diceRoll();
console.log(1, diceResult[0]);
console.log(2, diceResult[1]);
console.log(3, diceResult[2]);
console.log(4, diceResult[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sort out your syntax errors. This answer only provides another way of getting access of those crucial `randomNumber`'s whose values you need to use later on.

As we've already highlighted on the comment section, you can't access a function scoped variable outside of that function in Javascript directly. There are various approaches you could take to make that possible... Here's one of them:

Let's let `diceRoll()` to return a resultObj of the roll, like below:

```
function diceRoll() {
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var Image1 = "dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src", Image1);

  var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var Image2 = "dice" + randomNumber2 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[2].setAttribute("src", Image2);

  var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var Image3 = "dice" + randomNumber3 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[3].setAttribute("src", Image3);

  var randomNumber4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var Image4 = "dice" + randomNumber4 + ".png";
  document.querySelectorAll("img")[4].setAttribute("src", Image4);

  return {
    One: {
      randomNumber: randomNumber1,
      image: Image1
    },
    Two: {
      randomNumber: randomNumber2,
      image: Image2
    },
    Three: {
      randomNumber: randomNumber3,
      image: Image3
    },
    Four: {
      randomNumber: randomNumber4,
      image: Image4
    }
  }
}
```

You will notice that I returned an object with 4 keys, each key representing a dice. Each dice has properties `randomNumber` and `image`. This way you can call `diceRoll` and access the result later by doing this:

```
var result = diceRoll();
```

The dices are rolled, now we can get the result by accessing the properties of the dices using `result` ... you could do this:

```
// Determining Winner
if (noOfChoices === "2") {if (result.One.randomNumber > result.Two.randomNumber) {$("#title").html(choice1 + " wins! ");}
else if (result.Two.randomNumber > result.One.randomNumber ) {$("#title").html(choice2 + " wins! ");}
else if (result.Two.randomNumber= result.One.randomNumber){$("#title").html("Oops, try again!");}
}
```

This applies to both dice 3 and 4.

---

Here's another simpler version:

```
function diceRoll() {  
  let DiceKeys = ["One","Two","Three","Four"];
  let resultObject = {};
  
  DiceKeys.forEach((keyName, index)=>{
    let diceRandomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    let diceImageSrc = "dice" + diceRandomNum + ".png";
    document.querySelectorAll("img")[++index].setAttribute("src", diceImageSrc);
    
    resultObject[keyName] = {
      randomNumber: diceRandomNum,
      imageSrc : diceImageSrc
    };
  });
  
  return resultObject;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this now

Comment: It says unexpected identifier at line:31 Which is  `Three: {` and it's referring to the `{` any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to put `,` on the return object

Comment: You can try it now, I have fixed that.

Comment: I would also suggest that you use a shorter version of your code as provided above. It will save you a few lines of Code.

Comment: Do I have to set the properties of randomNumber? Right now it says `index.js:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: randomNumber4 is not defined
    at diceRoll (index.js:32)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.js:98)`

Comment: lol! Because I copied your code. So we duplicated the `randomNumber3` so we must change the last `randomNumber3` into  `randomNumber4`. Check I have changed it.

Comment: I apologize for that, I've been doing this in hurry lol! really sorry.

Comment: Omg sorry it's my fault too, I changed it on my computer but not on the question, trying now

Comment: Let me know how it goes.